# AspNetCoreIdentity with MySql: Object must be the same type as the enum. MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.MySQLValueGenerationStrategy

Tags: mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to build `AspNetCoreIdentity` with `MySql` database.

I added all the necessary configuration and reached to the point where the project has successfully generated the `AspNetCore` tables migration.

But for table `AspNetRoleClaims` the EF core has generated `MySQLValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn` enum like this

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
     name: "AspNetUserClaims",
     columns: table => new
     {
         Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
             .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySQLValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
         UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(255)", nullable: false)
             .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
         ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
             .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
         ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
             .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
     },
```

But when I run the `update-database` command it gives me this error

> System.ArgumentException: Object must be the same type as the enum.
> The type passed in was
> 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.MySQLValueGenerationStrategy'; the
> enum type was
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.MySqlValueGenerationStrategy'.

But there is no such enum `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.MySqlValueGenerationStrategy`, so I am not sure why it is expecting this enum type.

Any idea how to fix it and what is the exact problem?